# Telerik chart not loading correctly (ajax/script issue?)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I have a page which contains user controls with **Telerik Charts** (grids also, but they work fine). From this page, the user can click on a button to be redirected to a "Printer-Friendly Version" type page, which opens a **new window** via javascript and goes through a slightly different view (for formatting and stuff), but the telerik code is all the same.

**The problem is**, my Chart displays just fine in the original window, but **the new window displays basically an empty chart with no data**. This bug is **only present in IE, and only applies to Charts**. Grids work fine, for whatever reason. I'm thinking this is due to differences in script caching between browsers -- correct me if I'm wrong, I'm semi-new to client-directed web development.

Anyway I read somewhere that Telerik has issues with loading data and/or js files when loaded via ajax, so maybe that's the problem? If so, how could I get around this? And if not, any ideas on what could be causing this issue? It's causing me a great deal of frustration, since a print preview page seems like it should be the easiest of jobs.

**Edit:**

The charts are being rendered as html (if somebody can explain how to render them as images, that would be awesome). And dev tools shows basically the same thing between chrome and IE. Whenever my web service goes back up ill WinMerge them and look for any peculiarities/differences between them. In the mean time, though, the "render as an image" concept sounds promising. That way I could just save the image from the first page, and insert it right into the print preview page, right?. And since it's a print-preview page, it's not going to need to be interactive or anything, so that'd work out nicely.

**Another (important) Edit:**

### ***These are probably the culprit...***

[image: Here are a few jQuery errors..but why?]

And here is a little more detail on that:

[image: not sure what <code>b</code> refers to, but it looks like it's the issue]

And here is a side-by-side of it working(in chrome) and not working (in IE):

[image: Looks like in IE it just isn't pulling any data]

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a print-specific stylesheet instead, e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

In which you specify the styling to apply when printing.

That way, you avoid reloading the page (duplicate database hits, etc.) and don't need to delve into the AJAX of Telerik's controls.

**EDIT:**

Regarding using an image rather than HTML, first make sure you won't lose any features/detail, then check out the `.Save()` method of the RadChart control. You could either save it to a memory stream, or if you want to re-use the image save it to a directory on the webserver and clean it up periodically. That way, you can just point your print version to the image and not re-generate it.

[This Telerik forum post](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/chart/rad-chart-export-to-xls-or-pdf-or-word-doc.aspx) may be of use.

Comment: Yeah, that was my suggestion too, but unfortunately the folks at product just reeeeeally want it in a new window. And I don't think I'm going to be able to do it in a new window without reloading everything, as I'm pretty sure I'd lose session. (security here is pretty tight)

Comment: That's a shame then! Are you rendering the charts as images or HTML? What can you see in the Developer tools in IE? There might be a clue in there especialy if you compare to FireFox et. al.

Comment: well, I was gonna add pictures, but our web service provider is down. So ill edit with whatever i can

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt Have edited answer to add suggestion about image, but not sure what would be causing the errors in your screenshots, sorry.

Comment: Well I can't use `.Save()`, as thats RadChart-only. IF there's a MVC Chart version of that that I could use, let me know.

Comment: Also, not to be the guy begging for +rep, but maybe you can help get this a little more attention by upvoting the question? I think I did a pretty good job on it :)

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt The correct way to get "attention" is to offer a bounty on your question. But I agree, your question effort is vote-worthy.

Comment: Yeah, if it isn't answered fully by the time I can put a bounty on it, I plan to add one. Thanks for all the help so far, by the way.